# Rails 5.2 fonts folder in assets throws a 404 (Not Found) error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, npm, fonts, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm currently working on a Rails 5.2 application. I installed an `npm` package. Within this package there is a `fonts` folder. In the `config/application.rb` file I configured the assets pipeline to include the `node_modules` folder:

`config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')`

This didn't work and I still receive the following errors display in the image below.
[image]

I get a `404 (Not Found)` Error but when I moved the `fonts` folder into the `assets` folder. 
[image]

In the assets precompile I have the following configuration:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules/access-nyc-patterns/src/')
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)\z/
```

When I run an output of all the path names in the assets the `fonts` folder is shown. Why is the `fonts` folder not loading.
[image]

In `application.scss`

```
// if @font-face is used it needs to be first imported first.
@import 'elements/fonts/fonts';
```

Why is it displaying this error?

Comment: How are you calling those fonts? Can you show us the code?

Comment: `// if @font-face is used it needs to be first imported first.
@import 'elements/fonts/fonts';`

Comment: You need to access them by adding the full path relative to the `fonts` folder. Did you do that?

Answer (score 1):

So the issue started with the path pass to the url for the fonts. This article basically guided me into adding the [web fonts to the asset pipeline](https://gist.github.com/anotheruiguy/7379570).

```
/**
 * Fonts
 */

// Dependencies
@import 'config/fonts';

@mixin font-face-all($name, $file, $weight: normal, $style: normal, $formats: ()) {
  @font-face {
    font-family: "#{$name}";
    src: url(asset-path('#{$file}.eot'));
    src: url(asset-path('#{$file}.eot?#iefix')) format('embedded-opentype'),
         url(asset-path('#{$file}.woff')) format('woff'),
         url(asset-path('#{$file}.woff2')) format('woff2'),
         url(asset-path('#{$file}.ttf')) format('truetype');
    font-weight: $weight;
    font-style: $style;
  }
}

@mixin font-face-otf($name, $file, $weight: normal, $style: normal, $formats: ()){
  @font-face {
    font-family: "#{$name}";
    src: url(asset-path('#{$file}.otf')) format('embedded-opentype');
    font-weight: $weight;
    font-style: $style;
  }
}

@mixin font-face-ttf($name, $file, $weight: normal, $style: normal, $formats: ()){
  @font-face {
    font-family: "#{$name}";
    src: url(asset-path('#{$file}.ttf')) format('truetype');
    font-weight: $weight;
    font-style: $style;
  }
}
```